# Defining two same group names in regex

Tags: java, regex

```
String strr = "{msg=1234,returnCode=123}";
Pattern pat1 = Pattern.compile("^\\{returnCode=(?<returnCode>\\d+)(,msg=(?<msg>.*))?\\}|(\\{msg=(?<msg2>.*),returnCode=(?<returnCode2>.+)\\})?$");
```

In fact, I want to only define returnCode in the regex, but the compiler throws:

> Named capturing group  is already defined.

How can I solve it? Maybe there is some easier way to do it. Thanks very much

Comment: Java regex engine does not allow duplicate named groups, but it can be worked around in most cases. You do not seem to need any regex when parsing the string provided (mere splitting it with `,` after trimming the leading/trailing `{` and `}` and then each item with `=` should suffice). Or, just match and capture all key-value pairs with a mere `"(?<key>\\w+)=(?<val>\\w+)"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew oh,thanks,then how to parse the string without regex?

Comment: @Edward See [Multiple Groups with The Same Name](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html#duplicate). You may remove the brackets, split by `,` and then split by `=`

Comment: @HamZa the way of spliting by ，is not right.if there is {"xx":"xx","yy":"yy"} in msg

Comment: @Edward: If it is JSON, use a JSON parser.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew oh, i know,thanks

Comment: And just an [example of one of the workarounds](https://regex101.com/r/bR0gP2/1).

Answer (score 1):

```
String strr = "{msg=1234,returnCode=123}";
Pattern pat2 = Pattern.compile("(?<key>\\w+)=(?<val>\\w+)");
Matcher m = pat2.matcher(strr);
while (m.find()) {
    if (m.group("key").equals("returnCode")) {
        System.out.println(m.group("val")); // prints 123
    }
}
```